# Why do I need a default docker network to start a common docker network for two docker-compose projects?

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose, docker-network

I've got two projects (a and b) which both have a docker-compose.yml file. I now want one of the projects to be able to call a service of the other project and as far as I know I need to create a common docker network for that. So to create a minimal example I made two folders (`a/` and `b/`) which both contain a `docker-compose.yml` file.

This is the one in folder `a/`:

```
version: '3'

services:
  common_server:
    image: ubuntu
    ports:
      - 4444:4444
    command: >
      bash -c '
      apt update && apt install netcat -y && 
      while true; do echo -e "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n\npong" | nc -k -l -p 4444 -q 1; done'
#    networks:
#      - my_network

  project_a:
    image: ubuntu
    depends_on: 
      - common_server
#    networks:
#      - my_network
    command: >
      bash -c '
      apt update && apt install curl -y && 
      while true; do echo "Calling the container";  echo "AAAAAAAA"; curl common_server:4444; sleep 10; done'

#networks:
#  my_network:
#    driver: bridge
```

This sets up two things:

- `common_server`: a simple ping/pong server which responds "pong" to every request it gets
- `project_a`: a simple client which calls the `common_server` every 10 seconds

This works great like this. I quickly checked the docker networks using:

```
$ docker network ls
NETWORK ID          NAME                DRIVER              SCOPE
5ac503033848        a_default           bridge              local  <== THIS NETWORK WAS CREATED
1f65f9c91441        bridge              bridge              local
72fcb38f2060        host                host                local
b76cd7ef1ac9        none                null                local
```

I've got a second docker-compose.yml file in the folder `b/` from which I also want to call the `common_server` defined in the file above. So I uncommented the lines with the network in the file above to enable `my_network`. Running that also works great.

When I check `docker network ls` again I also see the second network it created:

```
$ docker network ls
NETWORK ID          NAME                DRIVER              SCOPE
5ac503033848        a_default           bridge              local  <== CREATED BY THE FIRST RUN
f0a42e17007b        a_my_network        bridge              local  <== CREATED BY THE SECOND RUN
1f65f9c91441        bridge              bridge              local
72fcb38f2060        host                host                local
b76cd7ef1ac9        none                null                local
```

I then started the second docker-compose file:

```
version: '3'

services:
  project_b:
    image: ubuntu
    command: >
      bash -c '
      apt update && apt install curl -y && 
      while true; do echo "Calling the container";  echo "BBBBBBB"; curl common_server:4444; sleep 10; done'
    networks:
     - a_my_network
networks:
  a_my_network:
    external: true
```

That also works. It can call the `common_server` from the first docker-compose file.

**The first question I have: Although I define the network as `my_network` in the first file, it is called `a_my_network` by docker. Is there a way to define the network so that I can call it the same in both docker-compose files?**

I then decided to remove those two networks using `docker network prune`, and start again. Unfortunately, when I now run the first file again I now get the following error:

```
$ docker-compose up
Creating network "a_my_network" with driver "bridge"
Starting a_common_server_1 ... error

ERROR: for a_common_server_1  Cannot start service common_server: network f0a42e17007bc0f352042f5394aef65be18bb12c7836e8864ecb734f83a421d7 not found

ERROR: for common_server  Cannot start service common_server: network f0a42e17007bc0f352042f5394aef65be18bb12c7836e8864ecb734f83a421d7 not found
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

**So my second question: Why can I only start the first docker-compose file if I first create the `a_default` network by not explicitly defining a network?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you declare the network in the second file you can explicitly specify its [`name:`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#name-1).

```yaml
version: '3.7'  # minimum of 3.5
networks:
  my_network:
    external: true
    name: a_my_network
```

As you note at the beginning, though, [Compose creates a `default` network for you](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/), and if you don't explicitly declare `networks:` for a container it will attach to `default`.  You can [reconfigure the `default` network](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/#configure-the-default-network) however you'd like.

So probably what I'd do here is not declare `networks:` in the first `docker-compose.yml` file at all.  In the second I'd make the `default` network point at the first file's `default` network, and also not configure `networks:` for containers.

```yaml
networks:
  default:
    external: true
    name: a_default
```

Compose keeps track of what's going on primarily by using labels on objects.  These are generally hidden from you but they're one of the things included in the very detailed `docker inspect` output.  In your last example, if you manually `docker network prune` a network out from under Compose, it starts to get confused.  On the other hand, if you just comment out the network you manually created and re-run `docker-compose up`, Compose should notice that it's created a network that's no longer needed and clean it up for you.

Comment: Ok, it took me a while to get this working because I overlooked your commend on the minimum version needing to be 3.5, but now it works, so a big thanks for that! I wonder though; since I can't control the folders that other people clone the projects into, I wonder whether I could make this work independent from the docker labels so that I don't need to put a big fat `NOTE` in the readme about keeping the project folder name the default? Any ideas on that? Or is that simply impossible?

Comment: You can manually specify the `name:` of the default network in the first `docker-compose.yml` too.  That will limit your ability to run this set of Compose files multiple times in parallel, but there's not a specific downside beyond that.

Answer (score 1):

You can alter the network name with the -p or --project-name flags or the COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME environment variable.

And see here maybe: https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/#use-a-pre-existing-network

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately that only changes the project name, which only changes the prefix, and not the complete network name itself. So `-p my_project` would make the network name `my_project_my_network`. That way I still can't have the same network name in both docker files.